# Resistors In series with voltage divider

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, series

just a heads up - i'm a complete beginner, so thanks for your patience in advance :)
I'm trying to get an LED light to light up, with 3 resistors in series (with voltage divider). [Here's my scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q720c.jpg):

> Source (8,6 V) -> 330Ω (resistor) -> 100Ω (potentiometer) -> yellow 3mm LED-> 330Ω (resistor) -> ground

and so the current goes like this: `? -> 26 mA -> 20 mA -> 20 mA -> 0 mA`
meanwhile Voltage goes like this: `8,6 V -> 4,9 V -> 3,7 V -> 3,7 V -> 0 V`

My questions:

1. why is the LED not lighting up ? it gets 3,7 V and 20 mA which is more than enough. (The LED works, tested with 2 V and 13 mA; 5 V and 27 mA (with just one resistor, no series))
2. why is there no LED voltage drop ? there should be ~2.1 Volt drop since it's a yellow LED.
3. It just seems like there is no LED, but a simple wire instead. Since voltage and current remain the same before and after LED light. Why ?

Comment: Draw a circuit of what you did or post a picture.

Comment: Updated my post with a link

Comment: You need to read up how breadboards work, where your LED is plugged in, all the pins as well as the jumper wire and the resistor are all using the same contact.

Comment: Unless you draw an schematic (hint: there's a built-in in tool in EE.SE) you won't get much love here.

Comment: @Povilas Gintutis: if your components are really in series it is not possible that you have different currents (26mA, 20mA, 0mA) going through them. Review Kichhoff's Laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a short circuit across your LED.

The rows of pins on a breadboard are commoned together, so you have to use different rows for the two pins of the LED.

Also, the current is always the same at every point of the circuit. That's one fundamental rule for series circuits.

Comment: oh, i see. It's working now. But i don't get why both current and voltage differ after each component then. Isn't my creation in series ?

Comment: The voltage is supposed to be different. I guess you measured the current incorrectly. Did you maybe stick the probes on either side of each component? Then you effectively shorted that component out and measured the current through the rest of the circuit (which may vary depending on which component you shorted out). Current is measured by replacing a wire link _between two components_ with the ammeter, so to speak.

Comment: I check it by probing cathode of LED and ground, to see how much current flows after it passes through LED.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As with every row of 5 pins, they are all shorted internally: -

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail ?

Comment: Read this: https://www.eleinmec.com/article.asp?10

Comment: oh, so in my case, the current flows through the row rail itself instead of the LED, because it's less resistant, right ?

Comment: yes, current always tries to flow in path of least resistance. There is a dead short, so all the current will pass straight past the LED without lighting it